# Display User Role Next To Comment

Tags: user-roles, comments

I've search around but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for and for the first time I don't even know where to start.

How do I display the user role (Admin, Editor, Author Contributor, Custom) next to a registered user's comments?

With a condition to display something else if they're not a registered user.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the user id to this function:

```
function get_role($user_id)
{
    if(is_int($user_id))
    {
        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) 
        {
            foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
                echo $role;
        }
    }
    else
        echo "Something else";
}
```

Comment: Does this go into comments.php or in functions.php

Comment: @GlentonSamuels, No different! but it's better to put it in functions.php